# Passing RichText attributes to function onChange

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, javascript, block-editor, wp-editor

I have four RichText elements in a custom Gutenberg block I am developing, and they are all very similar except for the "name" attribute, which is currently hard-coded. What I need to do is pass in the value of the change, and the value of the name attribute to a function before using SetAttribute. Is this possible?

```
// the function that I need to use to SetAttribute after seeing the name   
const onChangeTitle = ( value, name ) => {
    console.log(name);
};

// the RichText element
<RichText
    tagName="h3"
    className="h5 text-light"
    placeholder="Link Title"
    name="linkOne"
    value={ linkOneTitle }
    onChange={ ( value ) => onChangeTitle( { value, name } ) }
/>
```

I can post the full code, but there are several different fields and elements that I didn't want to have clutter the post. The RichText works just fine and if I use SetAttribute in the `onChangeTitle` it works without issue to save the title, but I need to set the title in a specific way based on the `name`.

Comment: I can't help but think there's a better approach. What's your use case here? Does the field need to be a particular format? Perhaps a better option would be to create a component that wraps RichText?

Comment: The context is that I have four instances of the same RichText that the user can enter (in a pre-formatted list, like a pricing table). What I was hoping to do is use a single function `onChangeTitle` to be able to set the value for each of the titles depending on which one was clicked or altered.

Comment: I'm trying to prevent redundant code like `onTitleOneChange` `onTitleTwoChange` etc, so that I can use one function for the same title setting, but just determine which title to set based on the `name` attribute in the RichText component.